# Replacing text with shell script ending with an extension

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need some inputs on how to achieve this:

I need to replace a text in a file, using shell script, the text which i need to replace ends with .ear, for example below:

`/home/export/files/list/aa_bb_cc.ear`

The shell script should replace the `aa_bb_cc.ear` with say, `replaced.ear`.

That is the line after substitution should be:

`/home/export/files/list/replaced.ear`

I did read online about this, and came to know about sed command. The problem which i have, is that i don't know before hand what the text to be replace would be, that is, i know the text to be replace would be something *.ear (in an attempt to match aa_bb_cc.ear)

Now, how can I do this? I tried to use "*" in sed however it didn't work

Comment: You need to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: "How do I rename files" is barely a programming question. It's especially not a programming question if you haven't included your attempt to solve the problem. Try to show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. An answer on StackOverflow needs a question with source code in it.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's|[^/]*\.ear|replaced.ear|' file
```

or

```
sed 's|[^/]*\(\.ear\)|replaced\1|' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo /home/export/files/list/aa_bb_cc.ear | sed 's/[^/]*\.ear/xxx.ear/'
/home/export/files/list/xxx.ear
```

since regex match is greedy, you need to specify to match non-slash char.  Dot matches any char, so to specify literal dot you have to escape with back-slash.

Comment: You can avoid problems with `somepath/lib.ear/aa_bb_cc.ear` with `sed 's/[^/]*\.ear$/xxx.ear/'`